# If my program exits with status 1 when the execution fails do I also have to include an exit with status 0 if the execution was successful?

Tags: java, error-handling, exit

I am writing a program in Java where I need to make sure I have correct error handling, that is I need to follow Java's standard convention and let the program exit with either a successful or non-successful status.

I have included a `System.exit(1)` whenever I am "catching" an error in my program. Now I wonder if I also need to provide a `System.exit(0)` in my program as well? In such case where in my program do I add the exit with status 1?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want your program to exit immediately at a certain point, yes. If just let your program finish normally, the jvm will return 0 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

a VM will shut down under 3 conditions:

1. It is told to do so by the OS; in posix terms, because it receives a SITERM signal. If you press CTRL+C in a terminal that has the jvm on the foreground, that's how that works. If you open the windows 'task manager' application, click it, and hit 'end process', that's what happens. If you type `kill pidOfJavaProcess` in the terminal, that's what happens. The process return code when SIGKILLing is generally uninteresting; usually it's 143 (128+the int value of the signal), and it's asking for info you already know: Yes, it exited due to you telling it to. You already know that.
2. You tell it to, using `System.exit`. Yes, by convention, return 0 to indicate 'success' and non-zero otherwise.
3. All Threads that the VM is running have either died, or have their daemon flag set (done with `thread.setDaemon(true)`). In this case, the VM decides there is nothing left to do and exits, with error code 0.

Of course, if you force kill it (SIGKILL), then it ends too, but it won't run shutdown hooks, there's nothing you can do in the java app to stop this. The error code, naturally, is just 128+SIGKILL and it's again uninteresting.

Because of rule #3, you don't NEED to write `System.exit(0)`. However, because the model of 'lets just wait for all threads to exit' tends to lead to apps that hang, and 'proper cleanup' cannot be done without shutdown handlers (because the system user can CTRL+C your app or kill it) you SHOULD run `System.exit(0)` to reduce the # of routes your code has to deal with.

So, MUST you? No. SHOULD you? Yes - because it is a good idea.